# How can I log the termination/any end of an SSIS package?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, ssis, sql-server-2012, break

I've got an SSIS package (targeting SQL Server 2012) and I'm currently debugging it. What I'm after is how to log that the SSIS package has finished **or stopped** by any methods.

The closest ones look to be 'OnExecStatusChanged', 'OnPostExecute', and 'OnPostValidate' however NONE of these provide any log messages when I *break execution* in Visual Studio.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: SSIS Logging Options]

I suspect the answer may be "you can't", but I want to see if there are perhaps more exotic solutions before I give up.

Comment: Just curious, why are trying to find this out?

Comment: I want to be able to match a PackageStart event with an end event, regardless of how it was ended (Visual Studio break or PackageEnd).

Comment: I do not know which problem you are trying to solve, you could call your package from a newly created parent package and do something after the package is finished no matter its condition. Having a hookup when the package is stopped sounds very difficult to me as you already have foreseen.

Comment: I want a message put in the sysssislog table when the package is ended by ANY METHOD. Is that possible?

Comment: What I'm trying to solve, ultimately, is that PackageStart log messages are 1:1 with some sort of end messages, which is not the case with all logging enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have two options available that I can think of.
One has been highlighted above in using the pre and post execute functions. If you were to use this solution I would recommend using a table (Dim_Package_Log?) and inserting to this table using a stored procedure on pre and post execute. 
**Clarification:** This wont catch package breaks, just start, end and errors.

As you rightly identified though this would not record package breaks. To capture this I have implemented a view that utilises two tables.

```
SSISDB.catalog.event_messages

SSISDB.catalog.executions
```

If you do some "exotic" joins you can utilise the `execution_status` from executions and the messages from `event_messages` to find the information you want.

I can't remember which msdn page I found it, but this is what the execution_status means in `catalog.executions`

```
The possible values are created (1), running (2), canceled (3), failed (4), pending (5), ended unexpectedly (6), succeeded (7), stopping (8), and completed (9).
```

**Clarification:**

Below is a sample line of what SSISDB.catalog.executions outputs for each package execution from a Job:

```
43198   FolderName  ProjectName PackageName.dtsx    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10405   GUID    SERVICEACCOUNTNAME  0   200 2015-02-16 00:00:03.4156856 +11:00  20  18  7   2015-02-16 00:00:05.4409834 +11:00  2015-02-16 00:00:58.4567400 +11:00  GUID    SERVICEACCOUNTNAME      10324   NULL    NULL    ID  SERVER  SERVER  16776756    3791028 20971060    8131948 2
```

In this example there is a column with a value of 7. As detailed above this status changes based upon the end state of the execution of the package. In this case, successful. If the package breaks midway it will be captured in this status.

Further information regarding this ssidb capability is located at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878089.aspx) MSDN page.

Comment: So are records entered into SSISDB.catalog.executions like cancelled and ended unexpectedly? I'm not at a computer on my work network at the moment, but if this table does house this information by default than that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, this table records every possible end state of a job. It is what you are looking for.

Comment: Did this answer help you? / Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I think it helps, I haven't taken a look to verify yet though. It's not exactly what I want, in that SSIS doesn't put a message in sysssislog, but it could perhaps be part of a custom solution.

Comment: Is the answer a definitive 'No' in that the SSIS package itself is not capable of doing this, and something else would have to manually insert this information into sysssislog to capture the breaks in execution through visual studio? This answer has been very helpful, though the proper answer to this question is 'you can't', or at least 'the SSIS package cannot do this through out of the box configuration'. If you can add this to the top of the answer, I'll mark it as the answer. Could you also add the view you mentioned?

Comment: Updated answer, and I am sorry but I cannot post the view as it is IP of my workplace.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is a partly answer. What is covered here is to detect that a package is finished by an error of success. This you can do by calling the package from an another parent package.

[image: Playing with package result]

But if the package is forced to stop then this won't have any effect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't address the question which is how to log package breaks or things like process termination.